# Old Utilite Value can't find ls and won't give me a display

Tags: 12.04, arm

I have a Utilite Value that I'm trying to repurpose as a media computer. I honestly can't recall what I was last doing with it, but I have a 8 GB SD card that sort of boots. (It actually had a 4GB card in the slot when I found it that gave me errors similar to [these](https://www.theo-andreou.org/?p=983).)

So before going further, some basics:

```
root@utilite-desktop:~# lsb_release  -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

What I think is the main problem, I'll describe second, since I arrive at the second.

So first, if I connect it to my TV via an HDMI cable, I get a dialog box about the system running in low-graphics. The options to reconfigure graphics (this does nothing) and to toubleshoot the error send me in circles. The options to run low-graphics mode, regardless of whether a serial cable is connected to the front, each spit a bunch of stuff out, and then I can type using my Logitech K400 wireless keyboard and trackpad, but there isn't a prompt. It's just echoing. At least, typing commands doesn't give any output. If there is a prompt, it's actually off the left end of the screen by six characters, but the seventh column onward aren't acting like there's a prompt.

So if I connect that serial cable, when I try to run basic commands, I'm getting weird results.

```
root@utilite-desktop:~# which ls
/usr/bin/ls
root@utilite-desktop:~# ls
-bash: /usr/bin/ls: No such file or directory
root@utilite-desktop:~# /bin/ls -Al ~
```

and

```
utilite@utilite-desktop:~$ which ls
/usr/bin/ls
utilite@utilite-desktop:~$ which grep
/usr/bin/grep
utilite@utilite-desktop:~$ ls
-bash: /usr/bin/ls: No such file or directory
utilite@utilite-desktop:~$ grep
-bash: /usr/bin/grep: No such file or directory
utilite@utilite-desktop:~$ /bin/ls -Al ~
total 32
-rw------- 1 utilite utilite  186 Apr 18 02:37 .bash_history
-rw-r--r-- 1 utilite utilite  220 Apr  3  2012 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 utilite utilite 3486 Apr  3  2012 .bashrc
drwx------ 2 utilite utilite 4096 Apr 18 02:29 .cache
-rw-r--r-- 1 utilite utilite  675 Apr  3  2012 .profile
-rw-r--r-- 1 utilite utilite 8445 Apr 16  2012 examples.desktop
```

Given that I already have the computer, how can I repair things well enough to be able to create a card with a newer version of Ubuntu to be able to use for video conferencing, streaming, and maybe some light retro gaming? Is it just a matter of putting `/bin` in my `PATH`?

Thanks, all!